# Google Chrome extension to save open and pinned tabs

Tags: chrome

I like the extension FreshStart - Cross Browser Session Manager (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/freshstart-cross-browser/nmidkjogcjnnlfimjcedenagjfacpobb)

It is a browser session manager which save all open tabs (or selected) to a new session. Sessions are saved in the "FreshStart Sessions" folder in bookmarks, allowing you to synchronize it with other computers. When I save session I can click on the icon and open saved tabs again in a new window.

I am looking for a similar extension (**or other way**) to have possibility to save session (i will like if saving is like the "FreshStart Sessions" - folder in bookmarks), but with **pinned** tabs. So when i save session with pinned tabs and open the new session (saved one early), this extension (or other way) to have possibility to keep pinned tabs as they were before - pinned.

Any suggestions?

Best Regards!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE! I don't know of an extension that manages pinned tabs, but Chrome Extensions' API does allow to pin and unpin tabs programmatically. In case you are a developer, you could modify an existing extension to suit your need. Otherwise, can you explain why pinned tabs is important to your workflow? Maybe we can improve that part so you don't need the pinning.

Comment: Hi @CarlesAlcolea, im working as developer and I will try to achieve that programmatically if I can't find any solution.
Why it is important : on my personal computer i have several tabs that are pinned but they are not related to the work. Also on the working computer i have chrome with same pinned tabs and for work I am using different browser with pinned that are related to the projects that does not sync my bookmarks, logins etc with Chrome. Because I want the sync feature from Chrome I got to the idea just to use working tabs on Chrome.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you pin tabs in order to classify, differentiate them for the rest of the tabs, right? If that's the case, I'd suggest using the tab management extension I use myself. It's called "Tabs Outliner". It allows me to classify tabs and windows in any way I need. If that is not the case I didn't understand you and I'm sorry for not being able to help!